# JQuery selectmenu is not initializing after XMLHttpRequest

Tags: xmlhttprequest, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have selectbox and I using XMLHttpRequest to load values to second selectbox also I am using JQuery selectmenu. The problem is after I select an item from first selectbox the second selectbox changing but won't initialize JQuery selectmenu. Any suggestion?

> ```
> var xmlHTTP;
> function GetXmlHttpObject()
> {
>   xmlHTTP=null;
>   try
>   {
>       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
>   }
>   catch (e)
>   {
>       try
>       {
>           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");            
>       }
>       catch (e)
>       {
>           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
>       }
>   }
>
> }
> function getAdultRoom(room_id)
> {
>         if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
>         {
>           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
>         }
>        else
>         {
>           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
>         }
>
>         if(xmlhttp == null)
>         {
>             alert("Your browser not support the AJAX");   
>             return;
>         }
>         var $element = jQuery.noConflict();
>
>         var url = "ajax_fetch_room.php?room_id="+$element('#room_type').val()+"&side_check_in_date="+$element('#side_check_in_date').val()+"&side_check_out_date="+$element('#side_check_out_date').val();
>
>     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
>     {
>      if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)             {
>        document.getElementById("roomadult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
>                   }
>     } 
>     xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
>     xmlhttp.send(null); }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.    I added  $('select').selectmenu(); to onreadystatechange

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
               if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                 document.getElementById("roomadult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                $('select').selectmenu(); 
                }
              }
```